# what is the output of the <input type=file>?

Tags: html, file-upload, input

I'm trying to understand the file upload process and i'm curious to know every little detail about it.

At first, i wish to understand how the input type=file component works just after selecting a file from  the wizard given to the user. I remember once in one of my projects as a student, the absolute file path was taken after the file selection happens and the path string itself was stored in the database ( i remember the photo table type wasn't a Blob but a string) but now i think this is weird since i was reading about the data uri scheme and the fact that a file is converted/encoded in order to be sent to the server.. and here i wish to ask if the file typed input's output is actually the file data uri ? does the browser use the file absolute path (e.g C:\userdocs....\file.pdf) to locate the file on the disk and then convert it ?

well, i wish someone to make things clear about all this.

Best regards.

Comment: Data URIs are not really part of the process at all. The browser will store the path internally, locate the file on disk, and include it in the request that gets sent... Why do you want to know this, do you have a specific issue you want to understand the background of? If you're just curious, I suppose you could look in a browser's source code to see how exactly it is done

Comment: Thanks  for your answer, if the file path  is what actually sent to  the server, so when  and how will the file content will be read then ?

Comment: The file path is not sent to the server. The browser will read the file when the form is submitted and package it in the POST request that gets sent to the server. If you want to know how exaclty that is done, you'll have to look in a browser's source code

Comment: i've read in some sites about how the file data is included on the post request though..

Comment: You mean the file name and original path? No, that is not sent any more, as it's a privacy violation, however small. The browser will send something like `C:/Fakepath/name_of_the_file.jpg` the "fakepath" part being a quasi-standard now in all major browsers

Comment: yes my issue background is to make some html5/jquery file drag'n drop-upload plugins to work with java, all examples i found were with php , so now i'm making a research about all the uploading process and i don't want to have any holes in my mind :)

Comment: the data sent included  on the POST request is the file binary data like shown in here : http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_asp/article.php/c19555/Understanding-File-Upload.htm

Comment: It shouldn't matter what the browser does internally. What data is transmitted in a file upload is well defined. The data you get from the browser will be the same in Java, PHP, or any other server side language; how it is accessible to you on server side, should be defined by your server. I think it would be much more productive if you posed your question with the problem you are actually facing - namely making the upload work with your specific server environment

Comment: CORRECTION : after looking to the POST content on firebug i noticed that the browser converted the file, after being loaded on an input component into a byte array and not to a data uri.